# Calculate T(n)? Algorithm efficiency (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I get the whole Big "O" thing but I'm kinda confused on the whole "finding or calculating T(n)"

Heres one problem with a sequential search.
Instead of just giving me the answer please tell me how you got it

```
def sequentialSearch(alist, item):
    pos = 0
    found = False

    while pos < len(alist) and not found:
        if alist[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos+1
    return found
```

Comment: 1. Think of the worst case (i.e. the one requiring the most operations). 2. Count how many operations are required to process the worst case.

Comment: This one might be helpful: https://www.quora.com/What-does-T-n-mean-in-relation-to-O-n

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is a worst case estimate of how the run time of an algorithm is dependent on the magnitude/size of the input(s). Generally, look for repetitive logic (mostly recursion or a loop) within the algorithm. Then find out the input(s) on which the number of repetitions would be dependent on - in this case, it is the size of input 'alist'. Try finding the dependency between size/magnitude of input and the number of repetitive actions for the worst case scenario. Here, the worst case scenario would be if 'item' is the last element in 'alist' in which case the while loop would run len(alist) times. So, the time complexity is O(len(alist)) or O(n) where n is the magnitude/size of the input governing the run time of algorithm.